# Is there a difference between "getting" an item and "fetching" an item?

Tags: language-agnostic, naming-conventions

When would a class method be called `fetchItems()` rather than `getItems()`? Is there a difference?

`fetchImage()` vs `getImage()` etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Get" is usually considered a local action and involves little more than poking at memory. "Fetch" may involve reaching across the network to a remote server to access the resource.